# Identify this screw head (was: Security Torx)

Tags: screws, bolts, screwdriver

Am attempting to open an old device cover (an adapter) and it has these screws (please see attached image, sorry for the bad quality, I couldn't get better focus than this.)

Would really appreciate if someone could guide me identify it and/or point to where to obtain a driver for it. (Or even more awesome if any tips of opening it using any hack without a specialty driver, if possible!)

[image: picture of bolt]

### Update Addendum

Well I am happy to report that — thanks to the help and solution below — I have acquired & successfully opened the Tamper-proof/Security Torx screw using the bit! (see more bad images below, :D Though I notice that a kind contributor has edited my original picture and fixed some text too, thanks!) :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: While it's not perfect, the picture is perfectly good, really - shows what we need to see, even if the focus is slightly off.

Comment: Am glad it was good enough for the solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: One trick for taking a closeup shot, is to not.   Instead, back off a half-metre or so, take the photo, and then use a crop tool to cut out the extra.  But this one is perfectly adequate.

Comment: I resized the blurry picture to 30% of the original size with [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/). Still has not lost any information. Now you can resize your pictures next time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a tamper proof torx screw. There are torx bits with a hole in the center that will remove them, if you are bold you can try smacking the center pin with a punch at an angle (small ones usually snap off) and then a standard torx bit can be used to remove it.  Check  online and I bet you can find a tamper proof bit kit for under 15$.

Comment: Also Known As "Security Torx"

Comment: Thank you for centre pin smack suggestion!

Comment: Hm, if you really mash it though you might damage the screw and make it harder to remove.

Comment: I have seen people’s efforts to smack the center pin to cause the screw to bend or the casing break.... better to get the proper bits...

Comment: @spcsLrg Given that you can pick up a new security torx driver for < $1, shipped, (eBay), it's commonly easier to just get the appropriate bit. If you don't know the size, sets are a bit more expensive, but not much. While such sources may not give you the best quality, it should, at least, get a single job done.

Comment: Makyen, I agree i stated 15$ because over the years I have purchased several full sets of torx , Allen or hex with a dozen other styles of tamper proof or security bits for this amount.

Comment: Just in case you may already have a set of security hex bits/Allen keys... they are *sometimes* interchangeable at a push. Not all, but some hex sizes will work [loosely but not enough to slip] in Torx screws.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, that's what I'm going to do. Will get bits with the hole (which I assume would work fine with screws without pins as well, so that appears to be a wiser choice). Not trying smacking and making things worse. Thanks y'all.

Comment: I'd also recommend buying a good kit with a diverse set of bits.  Years ago I thought I'd save myself a bit of money by only ever buying specific bits (or the smallest possible kit that had what I needed, typically 3-6 of a single type); but after doing that a few times you end up having spent the cost of a decent kit but still end up having to buy new bits because you've got a much less diverse collection than the kit you didn't buy in the first place.

Comment: agreed with others, just buy a *cheap* bit set. Torx are finicky enough without being boogered up by a wayward hammer. Note the emphasis on CHEAP: IMO all Torx get rounded off or otherwise wrecked after not long, so no sense dropping $$$ for a snap-on set...

Answer (score 3):

Your picture shows a [Security Torx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torx) screw head.
[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/Screw_Head_-_Torx_Tamperproof.svg/40px-Screw_Head_-_Torx_Tamperproof.svg.png]

You can find a good overview on most common screw drives for identification on a specific [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives).

Comment: I never knew there was a wikipedia page with this info.Thanks!